# First request to Spring Boot Rest API endpoint which is hosted in Centos virtual machine shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, centos, shopify

**Setup**

- Spring boot application with different REST endpoints
- Centos virtual machine with Apache configured to send port 443 requests to 8080 where my Spring Boot application is running on

**Problem:**

- The first request after starting `Spring Boot` application to every endpoint gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, after refreshing it, it works fine until I restart Spring Boot application
- I am trying to integrate with Shopify and 1 request never comes through to the server, even though I have disabled everything in the firewall security for just that testing purpose, and mocked the request (which works with postman).
- Most of the requests from Shopify work well, but 1 very important does not
- If I use `ngrok` I can get that 1 request working for some reason

Please, can someone help me figure out what is the problem? I have tried many countless hours with the help of System Admin.

Comment: Can you check what is happening inside the application for the first request? 
1. Making the first request from within the centos virtual machine and see if it works fine, with localhost.
2. Logging and checking for the first request after deployment.

Comment: Maybe it could be a multithread problem? If i have a callback endpoint, which gets request pretty often during other operations. Do i need some extra configuration for the callback then?

Comment: By callback endpoint do you mean, you have an endpoint in your application that you provide as a callback to Shopify? if so, then I can't commit about it as I am not aware of the shopify APIs. Also, I would like to understand how you came to the conclusion of the multithreaded problem as from what I get you are not able to get it to work even for a single request, right?

Comment: I started exploring the idea of problem with multithreaded because nothing really fixed it. For example I am purchasing something from Shopify then my application gets a request and forwards it to a payment gateway. Payment gateway starts sending requests to my callback endpoint.. "pending" "pending" "pending". So I was thinking maybe this is causing problems with other endpoints.